# Multiplicação matriz pela matriz transposta em linguagem C

Tags: c, matriz, multiplicidade

sou novato em programação e estou tentando fazer um programa em linguagem C que **multiplica uma matriz 3x3 pela transposta dela e imprime o resultado**. Estou com dificuldade pra criar o algoritmo da multiplicação entre a matriz pela transposta dela.
Qualquer ajuda será de bom grado.

Segue o código:

bibliotecas usadas (`stdio.h` e `stdlib.h`)

```
int main(){

int mat[3][3], mat_transposta[3][3], mat_resultado[3][3];
int i, j;

// leitura matriz
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        scanf("%d",&mat[i][j]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            mat_transposta[i][j] = mat[j][i]; // transformação matriz principal p/ transposta (FUNCIONANDO)
        }
    }
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                mat[i][j] *= mat_transposta[i][j];// multiplicação da matriz pela sua transposta correspondente

            }
        }

            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                    printf("%d\t", mat_resultado[i][j]); // impressão matriz resultado (A SAÍDA TEM QUE SER NESSE FORMATO)
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
return 0;
}
```

**Então o X da questão é resolver o algoritmo a seguir** (*que está logicamente errado, eu sei*). Não consegui criar um padrão ( i e j) para a multiplicação, que pudesse ser implementado como o mínimo uso de comandos `for` para executar essa multiplicação.

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                mat[i][j] *= mat_transposta[i][j];// multiplicação da matriz pela sua transposta correspondente

            }
        }
```

sei que na 1ª multiplicação da linha 1 pela transposta `**i0j0*i0j0 + i0j1*i1j0 + i0j2*i2j0**`
e que na 2ª multiplicação da linha 1 pela transposta   `**i0j0*i0j1 + i0j1*i1j1 + i0j2*i2j1**`
e que na 3ª multiplicação da linha 1 pela transposta   `**i0j0*i0j2 + i0j1*i1j2 + i0j2*i2j2**`

e então
na 1ª multiplicação da linha 2 pela transposta `**i1j0*i0j0 + i1j1*i1j0 + i1j2*i2j0**`
na 2ª multiplicação da linha 2 pela transposta `**i1j0*i0j1 + i1j1*i1j1 + i1j2*i2j1**`
na 3ª multiplicação da linha 2 pela transposta `**i1j0*i0j2 + i1j1*i1j2 + i1j2*i2j2**`

e por último
na 1ª multiplicação da linha 3 pela transposta `**i2j0*i0j0 + i2j1*i1j0 + i2j2*i2j0**`
na 2ª multiplicação da linha 3 pela transposta `**i2j0*i0j1 + i2j1*i1j1 + i2j2*i2j1**`
na 3ª multiplicação da linha 3 pela transposta `**i2j0*i0j2 + i2j1*i1j2 + i2j2*i2j2**`

Um exemplo, se a matriz (`mat[i][j]`) inserida pelo usuário for 10, 0, 1, 3, 5, 2, -4, 2, 3. A matriz resultado (`mat_resultado`) terá na saída os seguintes números: 101, 32,  -37, 32, 38, 4, -37, 4, 29.

Comment: Não dá pra multiplicar uma matriz com menos de 3 `for` porque, para cada elemento `M[i][j]`, você tem que somar os elementos da linha `i` e da coluna `j`. Mas como você está multiplicando uma matriz pela transposta, dá pra simplesmente fazer o produto interno da linha `i` com a `j` sem materializar a transposta. É claro, ainda não dá pra fazer _in-place_, já que vamos perder os valores originais depois da primeira célula modificada, então precisa de mais dois `for` para copiar o resultado para a matriz original...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar o produto de duas matrizes é definido somente quando o número de colunas da primeira matriz é igual ao número de linhas da segunda matriz.

```
#define L 3
#define M 4
...
    int mat[L][M], mat_transposta[M][L], mat_resultado[L][L];
    int i, j, k;
    ...
    /* Multiplicação*/
    for (i=0; i<L; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<L; j++) {
            mat_resultado[i][j] = 0;
            for (k=0; k<M; k++) {
                mat_resultado[i][j] += mat[i][k] * mat_transposta[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

No seu caso em particular L e M devem possuir o mesmo valor, isto é 3.

===================

Dê uma estudada na definição de produto de matrizes para entender a utilização da variável k e seu loop.

Comment: porque vc criou uma coluna a mais para a matriz inserida pelo usuário `mat[L][M]`?    A `mat_resultado` foi igualada a zero por causa do lixo de memória anterior?

Comment: outra coisa é que na saída da `mat_resultado` o algoritmo está funcionando somente na primeira e na segunda coluna, ou seja, na terceira coluna o valor está saindo errado.

Comment: Tentei entender  o trecho `mat_resultado[i][j] += mat[i][k] * mat_transposta[k][j];` porém não tive sucesso. Se eu não estiver abusando da sua boa vontade, tem como vc me explicar um pouquinho desse passo, pois não entendi como o `k` é usado nesse código.

Comment: Na declaração das varíaveis `int mat[L][M], mat_transposta[M][L], mat_resultado[L][L];` trocando um detalhe da `mat_transposta[M][L]` por `mat_transposta[M][M]` fez o programa funcionar redondinho agora.